# Distribution problem: dinner with $20$ guests and $2$ different plates

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> Let's say we are organizing a dinner with $20$ guests. Every guests after his arrival he wants to eat pizza with probability $p=0.6$ and spaghetti with probability $1-p=0.4$, independetely from the others. So there is no time consumption, the host of the dinner decides to order earlier $16$ pizzas and $12$ spaghetti. What's the probability that not all guests can eat the food they prefer?

So, i guess this problem has to do with Bernoulli distribution or binomial distribution. I also guess we need to start from calculating the probability($P_A$) of that all guest will eat food of their preference and then to find the requested probability($P_B$) we will just do $P_B=1-P_A$. Maybe, having $20$ guests means that we cast an experiment $20$ times and and we consider that if a guest eats pizza, the experiment is succesful with the given probability $p=0.6$ (All these are just my assumptions)

Any hints on how to start?

Comment: "all guests can not eat the food they prefer" Don't you mean: "not all guests can eat the food they prefer"?

Comment: Umm I did some calculations without knowing Bernoulli distribution and it seems that I have reached an answer of $0.01759774808$ percent. Is this accurate? If so I could show the method but I am not too sure personally.

Comment: @drhab Yes. I just edited my question.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I don't know the solution yet but all answers are welcome obviously.

Comment: There is no point in knowing it if it is not right. If it is right I will be glad to inform you. Comment to me if my answer was correct somehow.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Sure, i will post if i come up with the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ denotes the number of guests that go for a pizza then all guests can eat the food they prefer iff: $$8\leq X\leq 16$$

So the probability of this event equals: $$\mathsf P(8\leq X\leq 16)$$ where $X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n=20$ and $p=0.6$.